# CS50 final project: Problem with upload file path

Tags: python, flask, cs50

Amateur coder & enthusiast here, first time asking... I'm working on the final project of the CS50 course. I'm building a website where you can register and upload certain documents. Everything seems to be running fine, but the moment I try to upload the documents, I get an Internal Server Error with the following message:

*The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.*

What is going on? Is there a restriction for uploading documents into a folder in the CS50 IDE? I can't seem to find the solution to this problem. Documents are required to be in PDF format and I've tried /documentos, /fp/documentos & ~/workspace/fp/documentos/ as file paths. Here is the code:

```
import os

from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, 
url_for
from flask_session import Session
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from werkzeug.exceptions import default_exceptions
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

from helpersp import apology, login_required

# Define uploaded documents destination and allowed extensions

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/fp/documentos/' 
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['pdf'])

# Check if extension is allowed.

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route("/primer", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def primer():
"""Prompts user to upload pre contractual documents"""
 if request.method == "GET":
     return render_template("primer.html")

 else:
     # check if the post request has the file part
     if "file" not in request.files:
         return render_template("sindocumentos.html")
     file = request.files["file"]
     #  if user does not select file, browser also
     # submit an empty part without filename
     if file.filename == "":
         return render_template("sindocumentos.html")
     if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
         filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
         file.save(os.path.join(app.config['/fp/documentos/'], filename))

     return render_template("successp.html")
```

Here is the HTML part:

```
{% extends "layoutp.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Subir carpeta
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/primer" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data>
        <div>
            Sube tu carpeta de documentos en un solo archivo PDF.
        </div>
        <div>
            El nombre del archivo debe tener el siguiente formato: 
           carpeta_nombre_apellido_año.pdf.
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <input type="file" name="file">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Subir</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

The flask trace goes as follows:

```
ERROR:flask.app:Exception on /primer [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/fp/helpersp.py", line 34, in decorated_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/fp/profesores.py", line 133, in primer
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config[UPLOAD_FOLDER], filename))
KeyError: '/documentos'
```

UPDATE: I have tried different absolute paths without any luck. I've tried using os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(**file**)) and also UPLOAD_FOLDER=os.mkdir('documentos2'). With the os.mkdir option, it gives me the same error message as before only this type the KeyError is 'None':

```
 File "/opt/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/fp/helpersp.py", line 34, in decorated_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/fp/profesores.py", line 124, in primer
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config[UPLOAD_FOLDER], filename))
KeyError: None
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

instead of

```
file.save(os.path.join(app.config['/fp/documentos/'], filename))
```

Not sure if this will solve your problem, but this is how a working file of mine looks like where I use the same attributes as you do. This is kinda the only different I could find. It could also be the path, are you sure that the full path is defined in your code and do you see any files uploaded in that path when you do the post request?

Example of full path:

```
/Users/username/Desktop/csv_tool/upload_folder
```